# php формирование json для yandex карт

Tags: php, json, битрикс, yandex-maps-api

Не получается сформировать json из php:

```
 <?
 require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
 $mask = array();
 if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")){

    $arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","PROPERTY_*");
    $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>14, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
    $i = 1;
    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){ 
        $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
        $ccords = explode(",", $arProps['coords']['VALUE']);
        $mask['features'][] =  array(
        "type" => "Feature",
        "id"=>$arFields["ID"],
        "geometry" => array (
            "type" => "Point",
            "coordinates" => [$ccords[1],$ccords[0]]
        ),
        "properties" => array (
        "balloonContentHeader" => "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>",
        "balloonContentBody" => "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>",
        "balloonContentFooter" => "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", 
        "clusterCaption" => "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка",
        "hintContent" => "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"
        )
        );
        $i++;
    }
 }

 echo json_encode($mask,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
 ?>
```

получаю такой вывод:

```
{"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"99","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["38.063632","54.922348"]},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https:\/\/yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка<\/a><\/b><\/font>","balloonContentBody":"<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'><\/p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:<\/em>  <input><\/p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'><\/p>","balloonContentFooter":"<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: <\/font> <strong>этим балуном<\/strong>","clusterCaption":"<strong><s>Еще<\/s> одна<\/strong> метка","hintContent":"<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки<\/s><\/strong>"}},
```

А хотелось бы:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {"type":"Feature","id":99,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[38.063632","54.922348]},"properties":{"balloonContentHeader":"<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https:\/\/yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка<\/a><\/b><\/font>","balloonContentBody":"<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'><\/p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:<\/em>  <input><\/p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'><\/p>","balloonContentFooter":"<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: <\/font> <strong>этим балуном<\/strong>","clusterCaption":"<strong><s>Еще<\/s> одна<\/strong> метка","hintContent":"<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки<\/s><\/strong>"}}
```

Подскажите, как записать?

Comment: дак добавьте после цикла `$mask['type'] = "FeatureCollection"` и дело с концом, или нет?

Comment: а как убрать кавычки с id , и кавычки в coordinates?

Comment: `intval($arFields["ID"])`, `[floatval($ccords[1]), ... ] `  вы бы расписали что ли в чем  разница,а то так и не заметишь сразу

Comment: Спасибо тебе дружище.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вижу в комментариях вам teran вроде подсказал что и как, я б еще посоветовал все это написать более экономно(производительность)

```
 <?require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");

 $mask = array(); 
 $mask['type'] = 'FeatureCollection'; // добавляем то, чего вам не хватало

 if (\CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")) {
      $arSelect = Array("ID", "PROPERTY_COORDS"); // в цикле вы ничего больше не используете, это излишки
      $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>14, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");

      $res = \CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);

      // $i = 1; зачем вам $i ?

      // fetch быстрее работает, и в $arSelect мы берем только то, что нам нужно
      while($arr = $res->Fetch()){ 
           $ccords = explode(",", $arr['PROPERTY_COORDS_VALUE']);
           $mask['features'][] =  array(
                "type" => "Feature",
                "id"=> intval($arr['ID']),
                "geometry" => array (
                      "type" => "Point",
                      "coordinates" => [floatval($ccords[1]), floatval($ccords[0])]
                ),
                "properties" => array (
                       "balloonContentHeader" => "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>",
                       "balloonContentBody" => "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>",
                       "balloonContentFooter" => "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", 
                       "clusterCaption" => "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка",
                       "hintContent" => "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"
                 )
          );
    // $i++; зачем?
   }
}

echo json_encode($mask,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

p.s. постарался минимально затронуть наз-я переменных, но желательно тоже использовать смысловую нагрузку в них.

Тут я вам просто советую, как лучше, ни в коем случае не влезаю в ваш код :)

Comment: спасибо за добавку=) сделал по подсказке teran, завтра попробую исправить на твой код, потестирую.  в php не очень сильно силен, сильно мотивирует желание переписать и Гугл помощь, т.к тормоза при скролинге карты достали.

Comment: вы вот это экономно и красиво назвали? :)

Comment: честно, как начал писать, хотел красиво, потом подумал, что это неправильно, так как тяжело будет разобраться человеку, уберу эти слова :) но производительность будет на много лучше

Comment: вынесите статичную часть массива из цикла вверх. а в цикле оставьте только присваивание `id` и `coords`. Последнее более эстетично вписать в `list($long, $lat) = explode(...)`.

Comment: это как вынести, пример можно?

Comment: быстрее должно работать это факт $arselect вместо 5 запросов уже 2

Comment: как нить так http://ideone.com/o6aIhF

Comment: так хитрожопно, не для слабых умов=) завтра попробую. спасибо.